# Citrix workspace has wrong keys in guest OS (Windows)

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout, virtualization, citrix

I have a regular en-US keyboard. Most keys (alphabets and numerals) work fine in Windows, except for few symbols like

| Key I type | Key echoed |
| --- | --- |
| / | # |
| < (shift + ,) | \ |
| > (shift + .) | | |
| ? (shift + /) | ^ |

And unable to type few keys like {,[, ], }

Any clue how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure the correct layout is set in the guest OS?

Comment: The guest OS works fine from a Windows Host. So should be fine there.

Comment: The last comment is hard to understand.